# Edit js files in war file in tomcat

Tags: javascript, tomcat, war

Is there any way to edit the client side files (js,html etc) in the war file so that it need not be redeployed to view the change. I have did the same in `weblogic`, but I'm not able to find the same in `tomcat`.